# *** missing separator. Stop. error in invoking a makefile

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, visual-c++-6

I have used Export Makefile option from VC++ 6.0 project.

Getting this error

```
make -f simu.mak 
simu.mak:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

These are few lines of my makefile

```
# Microsoft Developer Studio Generated NMAKE File, Based on simu.dsp
!IF "$(CFG)" == ""
CFG=simu - Win32 PC Debug
!MESSAGE No configuration specified. Defaulting to simu - Win32 PC Debug.
!ENDIF 

!IF "$(CFG)" != "simu - Win32 PC Debug" && "$(CFG)" != "simu - Win32 PC Release"
!MESSAGE Invalid configuration "$(CFG)" specified.
!MESSAGE You can specify a configuration when running NMAKE
!MESSAGE by defining the macro CFG on the command line. For example:
!MESSAGE 
!MESSAGE NMAKE /f "simu.mak" CFG="simu - Win32 PC Debug"
!MESSAGE
```

Comment: That does not look like a makefile at all, but like an error message produced by the tool that was supposed to generate the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a makefile.  It's an nmake file (as it says, right at the top of the file :)).  You cannot use GNU make with that makefile, you must use Windows nmake.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that. Thanks..!